# Pyinstaller executable not working on linux

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

I wanted to create an executable for my program on Linux but the file in the dist folder isn't recognised by the OS as a program. It says the file type is "shared-library" but it treats it as a file to be opened by another program.

I thought maybe there was an error in my code so I created a script with just a print statement and had the same issue. I'm using Pyinstaller 3.6 on Linux Mint 20.

`pyinstaller --onefile <script_name.py>`

Comment: Can you try using the latest version of `pyinstaller` (4.2)? Use `pip install --upgrade pyinstaller` and try creating the exe again.

Comment: Updated to the latest version. Still have the same problem

Comment: The file should run fine from the terminal `./dist/<app_name>`, but it wouldn't on double click, seems to be an issue with the bootloader, you can try reconfiguring it, refer to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5361).